# Shell: How to move all files but the last modified to another directory

Tags: shell

How can I move all files in a directory except the one with the most recent modified time?

Comment: I assume you mean a UNIX shell. Try `man find` for more information on the find utility. I think `newer` is the option you're looking for. Edit: derp. had `-mtime` rather than the obvious `newer`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming almost nothing:

```
mv $(ls -lt | grep ^- | awk 'NR>1 {print $NF}') other_directory
```

With `ls -l|grep ^-` we grep  for the plain files. `ls -t` sorts them by mtime, youngest first. Awk then strips the youngest and just prints the file names. Ain't Unix cool!?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming GNU coreutils:

```
stat -c "%Y:%F:%n" * |
sort -t: -n |
grep ':regular file:' |
head -n -1 |
cut -d: -f3- |
xargs mv -t other_directory
```

- `stat` to emit modified type and file type
- `sort` to sort by time
- `grep` to ignore subdirectories
- `head` to list all but newest file
- `cut` to extract only the file name
- `xargs` to provide file names as arguments to `mv`

Answer (score 0):

actually figured it out by using the below:

`find /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output -type f -maxdepth 1 -not  -cmin -2 -exec mv {}  /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/archive \;`

Comment: This appears to possibly leave more files unmoved than just the youngest one.